# Catching print statement from JavaScript in Swift using JSContext

Tags: javascript, swift, javascriptcore

I'm trying to evaluate some JavaScript in my iOS app using `JSContext`. It's working well however I am not able to catch `console.log()` statements. How can I get the results of these function calls so I can print them in Swift as well?

**Example Code**

```
    let jsSource = "var testFunct = function(message) { console.log(\"kud\"); return \"Test Message: \" + message;}"

    let context = JSContext()
    context?.evaluateScript(jsSource)

    let testFunction = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("testFunct")
    let result = testFunction?.call(withArguments: ["the message"])
    print(result!)
```

**Example Logs**

> Test Message: the message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone is struggling with the same thing, here's the answer in Swift 4.

```
    let javascriptContext = JSContext()

    javascriptContext?.evaluateScript("var console = { log: function(message) { _consoleLog(message) } }")
    let consoleLog: @convention(block) (String) -> Void = { message in
        print("console.log: " + message)
    }
    javascriptContext?.setObject(unsafeBitCast(consoleLog, to: AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "_consoleLog" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)!)
```

Now you can call `console.log()` in any subsequent `evaluateScript` calls `javascriptContext`.